# Is this claim true$(\xi \circ k)(s)=(k \circ \xi )(s)=0$ $\implies$ $k(s)=\zeta(s)=0 $ is true if and only if the Riemann Hypothesis is false?

Tags: complex-numbers, riemann-zeta, symmetry, riemann-hypothesis

It is well known that $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ is a verified functional equation for all complex $s$, where $\xi(s) = s(s-1) \pi^{s/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) \zeta(s)$.

let $k(s)=\xi(1-s)$ and $s=\alpha+\beta i$  be a complex variable  , $\alpha , \beta $: are real numbers . and $\beta \neq 0$ defferent from zero

-Is there someone show me if this equivalence is true :

$(\xi \circ k)(s)=0 $  $\implies$  $k(s)=\xi(s)=0 $ is true if and only if the Riemann Hypothesis (RH) is false?

I see this claim help us to proof or disproof RH.

note : i edited the question which has same goal with the precedent.

I would be interest for any replies or any comments. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that is true ?

Comment: You should write out explicitly your composition. That way I think you can answer your own question.

Comment: i'm showed that this claim is true which going to me to find that the derivative of zeta function has no zeros in the critical strip .

Comment: but your answer help me to affirm that it's true or no

Comment: pleas, i asked if this claim true under conditions that i wrote below .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I answered your question.
I hope my answer is clear to you.

Comment: ur answer is true if and only if $\beta =0 $ .i wrote in my first question for the imaginary part different from zero, but it's edited , and deleted

Comment: and now the question fixed for no nul imaginary part

Comment: Im sorry but I think you did not (completely ?) understand the answer.
I think you should read up a bit on complex numbers or related math ...
The answer I gave is complete ; there are no other cases to consider.

Comment: I understand well ur answer , look $\zeta(\zeta(s))=1/2 $if and only RH is true  implies that $(\zeta o k)(s)$  different from zero . see, $A$ implies $B$ equivalent to $\neg {B}$ implies $ \neg {A }$ .

Comment: Then what else do you want ?

Comment: you are just show that RH true implies that the composition is different from zero , pleas use the mathematical logic of 2 proposition u will get and obtain my claim .

Comment: I advice you to read well the claim  .

Comment: @ mick, pleas see ur answer , i'm not wondred that :if $\xi(\xi(s)) = 0 => \xi(s) = 0$ is true iff RH is true but i supposed that :$\xi(\xi(s)) = 0 => \xi(s) = 0$ is true iff RH is false, read well my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following propositions:
$$P(z): "\xi(k(z))=k(\xi(z))=0"$$
$$Q(z): "k(z)=\zeta(z)=0"$$
$$R(z): "\text{RH is false}"$$
So your problem can be stated as if the following equivalence relation is true: 
$$(P(z)\to Q(z))\leftrightarrow R(z)$$
Now the above biconditional statement is true if and only if $R(z)\equiv T$ and $P(z)\to Q(z)\equiv T$ or $R(z)\equiv F$ and $R(z)\equiv F$ where $T$ and $F$ stand for "true" and "false" respectively.

First take $R(z)\equiv T$ then there exists some $z_0$ with $\Re(z)\neq 1/2$ such that $\zeta(z_0)=0$. It is well known that zeros of $\xi(z)$ are precisely the non-trivial zeros of zeta function $\zeta(z)$. Therefore $\xi(z_0)=0$. By your definition $k(z)=\xi(1-z)$ and using the symmetry $\xi(z)=\xi(1-z)$ you just get $\xi(k(z))=k(\xi(z))=\xi(\xi(z))$. At $z_0$ we have $\xi(\xi(z_0))=\xi(0)=1/2$ a result you get from the functional definition of $\xi(z)$ without assuming any additional hypothesis. So $P(z)\equiv F$ and whatever the truth value of $Q(z)$ is one has $P(z)\to Q(z)\equiv T$. Therefore we have shown so far 
\begin{equation}
R(z)\to (P(z)\to Q(z))
\end{equation}
To check for the other direction notice that if $\xi(\xi(z))=0$ implies $\xi(z)=w_0$ where $w_0$ is a non-trivial zero of zeta function on the critical strip. Since there is no non-trivial zero on the interval $(0,1)$ then the statement $\xi(z)=\zeta(z)=w_0=0$ is false. Therefore the compound proposition $P(z)\to Q(z)$ is false. So for $P(z)\to Q(z)$ to be true you need now necessarily $P(z)\equiv F$ which also leaves $Q(z)$ free to take any of the two truth values because if $P(z)\equiv F$ then $P(z)\to Q(z)\equiv T$ whatever the truth value of $Q(z)$ is. But $P(z)\equiv F$ means
$$\xi(\xi(z))\neq 0$$
implying that $\xi(z)\neq w_0$ where $w_0$ is any non-trivial zero of zeta function. However this condition does not pin down any thing on the validity of Riemann hypothesis. Therefore 
$$(P(z)\to Q(z))\to R(z)$$
is not assured to be true. As a result your biconditional statement is not assured to hold true. But of course you have that the following is true:
\begin{equation}
R(z)\to (P(z)\to Q(z))
\end{equation}

Comment: thank you for this answer, then i i have one of "only if " part is true , and what do you see about it, does it helpful to make a poosible appraoch to RH?

Comment: Nice solution! Definitely worth the 50 reputation of the problem. +1!

Comment: @kbot, I see this claim help us to make a part of Riemann Hypothesis proof

Answer (score 0):

$\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$

You defined $k(s)=\xi(1-s)$.

So $k(s)=\xi(s)$.

Next you wonder if $\xi(\xi(s)) = 0 => \xi(s) = 0$ is true iff RH is true.

There is no reason to assume those 2 problems are related.

Notice that if $\xi(s) = 0$ this implies that $\xi(\xi(s)) = \xi(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Since $\frac{1}{2}$ is not $0$ your claim fails.

Q.E.D.

Comment: thank you, i put before $\beta \neq 0$  . i don't know how it's deleted

Comment: and for ur case it's  depend only for $\beta = o$

Comment: The $\xi(s)$ function is primarily used to show that the zero's of the Riemann zeta function must be symmetric around Re = 1/2 in the strip. If it helps to prove RH is currently not claimed or expected by any " serious " mathematician as far as I know.

Comment: but should be the imaginary part of roots of zeta function different from zero .

Comment: see well ur answer , and see what i wondred in my claim  , then it's not problem for me to accept ur answer .

Comment: and the answer that you put is true if and only RH is true  but my claim if and only if RH is false .

Comment: No your claim is false. Independant of RH.
Since I disproved it without considering RH.
QED.

Comment: if u don't considerat RH , then how  u get $\zeta(0)=1/2$ ,? for which $s $ ?

Comment: try to write ur answer according to my given data

Comment: @mick, did you read the above answer ?,then i have a part is true about my claim